# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.addMergedRegion

Tags: java

Hi I am trying to merge cell using poi. I have the `poi-3.5-FINAL.jar` in my `web-inf/lib` but still I am getting the below error:

```
context with path [/OFSAA80] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.addMergedRegion(Lorg/apache/poi/hssf/util/Region;)I] with root cause
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.addMergedRegion(Lorg/apache/poi/hssf/util/Region;)I
    at com.sample.Template.generateTemplate(Template.java:108)
    at org.apache.jsp.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:100)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
```

My code :

```
 HSSFRow mergedRow= sheet.createRow((short) 0);                        //Creating Report Header
 sheet.addMergedRegion(new Region(0, (short) 0, 0, (short)  4));
 HSSFCell mergedCell= mergedRow.createCell((short) 0);
 mergedCell.setCellValue(RRRConstants.REPORT_HEADER+selsch+"- "+scheduleName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing to `addMergedRegion` a [`org.apache.poi.hssf.util.Region`](https://web.archive.org/web/20110106193529/http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/util/Region.html) and in the method (that is deprecated) signature in the [`API`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html) and you should send a [`org.apache.poi.ss.util.Region`](https://web.archive.org/web/20110325160938/http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/Region.html) to avoid this error...

**I highly recommend** to download last version and use new method  [`addMergedRegion`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#addMergedRegion(org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress)).

```
public int addMergedRegion(CellRangeAddress region)
```

Older is deprecated:

> Deprecated. 
>   (Aug-2008) use `CellRangeAddress` instead of `Region`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your version is quite old, download the latest version of the JAR, you can do it from here:

http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/poi/3.12/poi-3.12.jar